# How can i check a word table cell value using vb

Tags: vba

Im a bit of a noob to vb. I'm trying to check if a cell in my table is nothing. I need it to run if the cell is greater than nothing. I've got this so far but have hit a brick wall.

```
If ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(Row:=4, Column:=13) > 0 Then

'Do something

Else

'Do Something Else

End If
```

Comment: Vbscript an VBA are two different languages. Please use the appropriate tag. (I suspect you need vba, not vbscript)

Comment: Hi Geert, I've remove the tag. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If Not IsEmpty(ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(4, 13)) Then
    'Do something
Else
    'Do Something Else
End if
```

IsEmpty() is returning true when the Cell used as atribute is nothing.
You want to do something with the Cell if it is not empty, so putting Not before IsEmpty will achieve this.

Comment: REVIEW: Can you elaborate a little bit? For now it's a low quality answer.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, it is better